# Why can't the github account be logged in?

Tags: github

Recently log in to my github account, then jump to https://github.com/session, the browser shows: Your browser did something unexpected. Please contact us if the problem persists. What is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what `/session` is supposed to do, but clear your browser data for the domain and try again.

Comment: I tried the following:
1. Delete the cache of the site
2. Delete the history of the entire browser including cookies

But I can start logging in without opening the trace mode.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "But I can start logging in without opening the trace mode", and I still don't know why you're navigating to `/session`. Why don't you just go to https://github.com/?

Comment: Is the browser's plugin causing the login to fail, specifically which one did not find

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, I know. But first hit on Google, and the problem still exists:

- sign out of github.com
- visit a non-existing page on github, e.g. https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/
- on this 404 page, use the sign-in form
- you get redirected to `/session`, with the message "Your browser did something unexpected. Please contact us if the problem persists."

Solution: visit https://github.com, and sign in there